# why language is not getting translated in rwd theme magento?

Tags: magento, translation, magento-1.9

I am working with the new rwd theme , and have installed 4 languages .

English
French
German
Spanish

Although German is working perfectly fine , with emails for new order or account creation being sent in German

In french eventhough it has email templates , the emails are sent in English & some links like " add to cart , Account , about us etc are no translated ( but the translation file consists of these words)

Spanish also has the same issue.

how could i fix it ?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question? Or are you just configuring Magento?

Comment: Not programming related , its configuration related. First I installed the German language package thereafter French & Spanish .. German worked fine with no issues, But In other languages " add to cart " " account " , " About us" many more are not translated  .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A website. Perhaps you should post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0):

Blow path available all the email template, You can see that this are coming from `en_US` so this is manage language wise. Suppose you have different store view like French then there available `fr_FR`. Exact same location put all email file with your needed text.

> app\locale\en_US\template\email\

Comment: The email templates resides in fr_FR. Everything looks same compared with German. Still emails get sent as English  & moreover why does " add to cart " , " account"  still shows up in English even if changed to french..

Comment: Can you check in french store view which local set ?

Comment: For french store locale is set to french.